# Identify NFC tap in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, nfc

I have developed the WPF application to read the NFC card data. Application is working fine. But I'm getting the card data when user clicks a button.

But I want to get data when user tap the card. How can I identify NFC tap in WPF application?

Comment: I can add code only for reading the data. That is not related to question .

What I need to know is identify NFC tap. For that I cant find a code anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried using `proximityDevice.DeviceArrived` event?

Comment: @dhilmathy to use this I can not add namespace to my project

Answer (score 0):

`ProximityDevice.DeviceArrived` and `ProximityDevice.DeviceDeparted` events should help you in this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.proximity.proximitydevice.devicearrived
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.proximity.proximitydevice.devicedeparted

Comment: But how can I add this namespace to my project? Already I tried this. I can not find what is the reference I need to add to my project.

Comment: @Tom You can search & add reference to *Windows.Networking.Proximity.dll* and *Windows.dll* to your project.